# Error while installing Adobe Acroread in Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: package-management, software-installation, 15.10, dpkg, adobe

I am getting following error while installing Adobe Acroread in Ubuntu 15.10:

```
xyz@abc:~$ sudo dpkg -i /home/shiva/acroread-bin_9.5.5-1raring1_i386.deb 
(Reading database ... 442228 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../acroread-bin_9.5.5-1raring1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking acroread-bin:i386 (9.5.5-1raring1) over (9.5.5-1raring1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of acroread-bin:i386:
 acroread-bin:i386 depends on libatk1.0-0 (>= 1.12.4).
 acroread-bin:i386 depends on libc6 (>= 2.3.6-6~).
 acroread-bin:i386 depends on libfontconfig1 (>= 2.9.0).
 acroread-bin:i386 depends on libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1).
 acroread-bin:i386 depends on libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 (>= 2.22.0).
 acroread-bin:i386 depends on libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.12.0).
 acroread-bin:i386 depends on libgtk2.0-0 (>= 2.24.0).
 acroread-bin:i386 depends on libidn11 (>= 1.13).
 acroread-bin:i386 depends on libpango1.0-0 (>= 1.14.0).
 acroread-bin:i386 depends on libstdc++6 (>= 4.1.1).
 acroread-bin:i386 depends on libx11-6.
 acroread-bin:i386 depends on libxext6.
 acroread-bin:i386 depends on libxml2 (>= 2.6.27).
 acroread-bin:i386 depends on libxt6.
 acroread-bin:i386 depends on zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4).

dpkg: error processing package acroread-bin:i386 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.2~bzr0+15.10.20150627.1-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.58ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.4-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 acroread-bin:i386
```

Could anyone help sort out this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install a .deb file via the command line?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/40779/how-do-i-install-a-deb-file-via-the-command-line)

Answer (score 1):

You could certainly do the following:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

which might address the `dpkg` error:

```
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

But it looks as if you are installing an Acrobat Reader deb package from Raring Ringtail on to your Wily Werewolf installation. Try the following, which I have tested on Trusty not Wily. First some required files (needed on 64bit systems):

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-0:i386 libnss3-1d:i386 libnspr4-0d:i386 lib32nss-mdns* libxml2:i386 libxslt1.1:i386 libstdc++6:i386
```

as well as the gdebi installer:

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi
```

and then download and install the reader itself *directly* from the adobe website:

```
wget http://ardownload.adobe.com/pub/adobe/reader/unix/9.x/9.5.5/enu/AdbeRdr9.5.5-1_i386linux_enu.deb
sudo gdebi AdbeRdr9.5.5-1_i386linux_enu.deb
```

This tested nicely on Trusty Tahr and I have no doubt will work on Wily:

[image]

**References:**

- [Quick Tip: Install Adobe Reader in Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/04/install-adobe-reader-ubuntu-1404/)